# calculate dp for different screen for supporting multiple screens

Tags: android

I know there are many questions like this, I have read many blogs and questions on this and I am not satisfied by what I have understand.

I want to support multiple screens and resolutions like hdpi, xxxhdpi etc.
And i am using `dimens.xml` for this purpose. But m still unclear about how to calculate exact dp value for different screens.

For example if 48dp x 48dp `ImageView` is proper for hdpi device, what values should i define for xxhdpi device? Is there any fixed calulation just like there is for drawable images?

I am using these folder for trying to support multiple screens :

```
values-sw320dp-hdpi
values-sw320dp-xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi
```

There are few problems I am facing currently

- Though defining values in respective dimens.xml works almost for most of the devices, there are few devices which takes wrong values

For example I have Lg optimus G that is xhdpi device, but it reads values from `values-sw320dp-xxxhdpi`'s `dimens.xml` instead of xhdpi one

- I am not able to calculate the exact value for each resolution (hdpi,xhdpi etc), so the view which looks perfect in hdpi device, seems little large or small in xxxhdpi as I can't guess the value like if hdpi view size is 48dp then xxxhdpi should be of 64dp or something as I don't know the exact approach.

Also while searching for supporting different screens, I read many times about calculating dp at runtime based on density or calulating pixels etc.

I am too confused about all this. Please help me in understanding and learning the proper way of making responsive apps.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use these complex name folders? What do you need to do with your images? I think almost always values, values-large, values-xlarge are enough

Comment: Those file names aren't user defined. They are resource qualifier variations that are/can be generated by android studio. Then when an app is loaded on the device, choosing which resource to use is taken care of in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to specify different sizes for Views.

If you want the width of an ImageView to vary based on the size of the screen, create a new dimension in your `dimens.xml` file called `image_view_width` (for example).

This then essentially creates a copy of the `dimens.xml` but adding the 'Size' qualifier. This will create another version of the `dimens.xml`file, and any device that meets your specified qualifications will use that version of `dimens.xml`. You then add `image_view_width` to this new file and give it a different (smaller/bigger) value. You can do this as many times as you want and with as many different qualifiers as you want.

Finally, when you want to use this value in your layouts, you only have to type:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/image_view_width"
```

and android will do the rest for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am already following this approach with sw-320dp-xhdpi/xxhdpi etc. But then my question is if i set image_view_width to 48dp for hdpi device, what value is should set to image view_width for xxhdpi ? How to count that values?